# Is this loop possible (EE2) ? I have attached an image what i need exactly. Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Tags: ee, loop

{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" limit="1" category="2" sort="asc" entry_id="16"}

```
<li>Show Category title of category2    

    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" limit="1" category="2" sort="asc" }

    <li>Show subactegory title of category2 

        {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" limit="1" category="2" sort="asc"}

                <li> [![Sub category entries][1]][1]<li>

        {/exp:channel:entries} 

    <li>

    {/exp:channel:entries} 

</li>
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use the entries tag within the entries tag. Also you should avoid calling the channel entries tag multiple times because it is quite an heavy operation. You should use either an embed or Stash. Stash is a better option to speed up page loading.

An example of an embed (I haven't tested if you will get the desired results. This example should get you started though):

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" limit="1" category="2" sort="asc" entry_id="16"}

    <li>Show Category title of category2    

        {embed="[folder-name]/[template-name]"}

    </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Put this in the embed template:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" category="2" sort="asc" }
{if count == 1}
<li>Show subactegory title of category2 
{/if}
<li> [![Sub category entries][1]][1]<li>
{if count == total_results}
</li>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```